# C - getaddrinfo()

Tags: c, getaddrinfo

Can someone help me to get the IPs of google.com?
I can't find any good resource on this.
Most tutorials on C network programming create a client socket and a server socket on the same computer. (I don't know in which situation that would make sense) 
And none of the codes on beej.us worked for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct addrinfo* res = NULL;
    getaddrinfo("google.com", "443", 0, &res);

    struct addrinfo* i;

    for(i=res; i!=0; res=res->ai_next)
    {
        printf("%s\n", res->ai_addr->sa_data);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
�
�
�
���$u
���$u
���$u
���"u
���"u
���"u
��� u
��� u
��� u
���&u
���&u
���&u
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: `for(i=res; i!=0; res=res->ai_next)`?  Why are you checking `i != 0` if you're iterating with `res`?  And `res->ai_addr->sa_data` isn't a string printable with `%s` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In This statement `i` is never being modified in loop body, and because it is not initialized, it never even enters the loop:

```
for(i=res; i!=0; res=res->ai_next)
{
    printf("%s\n", res->ai_addr->sa_data);
}
```

Additionally, you are missing a few other parts.  The following steps are part of a full example linked below:

Create the following instances of `struct addrinfo`:

```
struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo *ptr = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;
```

Then initialize Winsock

```
   // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
```

Setup the `hints address info` structure

```
ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
```

Call `getaddrinfo`

```
dwRetval = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &result);
if ( dwRetval != 0 ){//handle error}
```

Now, for example based on above, your loop would look like:

```
   for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {//
```

Entering "www.google.com" 0 on the command line for the complete example (linked below) will look similar to this:
 [image]

This full Windows [example is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo).  ***Note***: Bug in code, i.e. ptr->ai_cannonname can be null with "www.google.com" so change this line to test before calling:

```
if(ptr->ai_canonname) printf("\tCanonical name: %s\n", ptr->ai_canonname);
```

A full Linux [example is here](https://gist.github.com/jirihnidek/bf7a2363e480491da72301b228b35d5d).

Answer (score 8):

First, you never modify `i` inside of the loop so you end up with an infinite loop.  You need to change to loop statement to:

```
for(i=res; i!=NULL; i=i->ai_next)
```

Regarding the output, the `ai_addr` field is of type `struct sockaddr *`, which is a pointer to a generic socket address struct, and its `sa_data` field is just a binary blob of the data for that address, not a printable string.

To print these values correctly, you need to `inet_ntop` function.  First, you need to inspect `ai_addr->sa_family` to see if it is an IPv4 address or an IPv6 address.  Then  you'll need to cast `ai_addr` to either a `struct sockaddr_in *` for IPv4 or `struct sockaddr_in6 *` for IPv6, then pass the `sin_addr` or `sin6_addr` field respectively to `inet_ntop` along with the address family to convert it to a string.

```
for(i=res; i!=NULL; i=i->ai_next)
{
    char str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    if (i->ai_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        struct sockaddr_in *p = (struct sockaddr_in *)i->ai_addr;
        printf("%s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET, &p->sin_addr, str, sizeof(str)));
    } else if (i->ai_addr->sa_family == AF_INET6) {
        struct sockaddr_in6 *p = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)i->ai_addr;
        printf("%s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &p->sin6_addr, str, sizeof(str)));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
172.217.10.238
172.217.10.238
172.217.10.238
2607:f8b0:4006:813::200e
2607:f8b0:4006:813::200e
2607:f8b0:4006:813::200e
```

Comment: this looks great and helped me a lot! i am new to sockets so i have another question - why is it printing the same ip address 3 times?